# Ошибка сегментации в массиве структур

Tags: c, структуры

Моя задача отсортировать поля массива структур. В 33 строке ловлю ошибку segmentation fault ( core dumped ). Буду признателен пояснениям. Для отладки оставил в структуре всего 2 поля (для наглядности) - а так их 6.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <control.h>
#define M 3

struct NamesOfFiles {       
    char name[8]; /* 8 symbols max */
    char type[M]; /* 3 symbols max */
}
nmf[M]; /* массив структур из М элементов */

     /* сортировка поля сируктуры */
            void sort(struct NamesOfFiles nmf[M]) {
    unsigned int i, j, nmin;
            struct NamesOfFiles temp[M];
    for(i = 0; i < M - 1; i++) {
                        nmin = i;
                        temp[i] = nmf[i];
                    unsigned int i, j;
    /* внутренний цикл */
                for(j = i + 1; j < M; j++) {
                if (strcmp(nmf[j].name, nmf[j - 1].name) < 0 ) { 
                    nmin = j;
                    }
                }
                    temp[nmin] = nmf[nmin];      /* segmentation fault ( core dumped ) here */
                     nmf[nmin] = nmf[i];
                     nmf[i] = temp[i];
                              }
                          }       

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    struct NamesOfFiles nmf[M];
        /* заполнение структуры */
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        printf("Введите имя декриптора:\n");
        scanf("%s", nmf[i].name);
        printf("Введите тип декриптора:\n");
        scanf("%s", nmf[i].type);
    }
     sort(nmf);
   /* вывод отсортированного поля структуры */
    int q;
    for( q = 0; q < M; q++ ) {
        printf("%s", nmf[q].name);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: А про юнит-тесты можно поподробнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном коде в функции `sort` имеется следующий код:

```
unsigned int i, j, nmin;
...
for(i = 0; i < M - 1; i++) {
...
    unsigned int i, j;
    for(j = i + 1; j < M; j++) {
        if (strcmp(nmf[j].name, nmf[j - 1].name) < 0 ) { 
            nmin = j;
        }
    }
    temp[nmin] = nmf[nmin];
...
```

Второе объявление переменных `i,j` скрывает первое - в памяти создаются новые переменные и начиная с места их объявления и до конца блока все обращения к переменным с именами `i,j` интерпретируются как обращения к их второй копии. (В языке C разрешено объявление переменных с одинаковыми именами в разных областях видимости. Обращения к таким переменным интерпретируются как обращения к переменным в ближней области видимости [самой глубокой вложенности]).
Так как переменные не инициализированы, то их значение не определено (можно сказать - случайно). На основе этих переменных (а именно `i`) формируются индексы массивов, по которым производится запись. Т.е. происходит попытка записи по случайному адресу, который вполне может выходить за пределы массива и выделенной программе памяти. Это обращение обнаруживает операционная система и прерывает выполнение программы.
Начальное значение переменной `j` во втором цикле также не определено - ошибка могла возникнуть и внутри этого цикла.

Comment: Я уже по совету более ранних комментариев поменял код, в результате почти все получилось, небольшие проблемы с сортировкой, но тут я уже сам справлюсь

Answer (score 1):

Просто так, для начала - после строки

```
unsigned int i, j;
```

идет строка

```
for(j = i + 1; j < M; j++) {
```

Так вот, чему в этом цикле равны `i` и `j`?
Мало того, что они скрывают `i` и `j` из предыдущего блока (что уже ведет к путанице), так они еще и не инициализированы...

Comment: Можно порекомендовать, определять счетчики прямо в цикле `for (int i=0; ...)`

Comment: Выбрал, на свою голову стандарт 89 года, сейчас перепишу под 99